# How to properly take image and save image?

Tags: c#

I made a Win-Forms application and want to Read a Image from the Webcam and save it to the disk and show it in a picture box. Everything works fine, but when i call the "Capture_Image()" function several times (on button14-click) i get a Error like "Object already in use"

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

private VideoCapture capture = null;
private Bitmap tempImg = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    capture = new VideoCapture();
}

public void Capture_Image()
{
    try
    {
        capture.Start();
        tempImg = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
        pictureBox2.Image = tempImg;
        pictureBox2.Refresh();
        tempImg.Save("C:/FHT59N3/Bildanalyse_Projekt/image.jpg",
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        capture.Stop();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        string message = "No Camera found";
        string title = "Please connect Camera";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}

private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Capture_Image();
}
```

Am i doing something wrong with the capture? Why do i get this error

Comment: I don't know the `VideoCapture` class but does it have a property that tells you if its running? Considering you call `.Start()` and `.Stop()` I'd say its not stopped yet and it tries to start it when you get the error.

Comment: And on which line do you receive that error?

Comment: if something goes wrong in your capture, the stop never happens..

Comment: The error only occours when the released exe file runs on a win7 machine. In Debug i can click like a maniac and didn't get any error. Bit i think the Idea of EpicKip is very helpful because the win7 machine i pretty slow and i guess the machine can't finish the start/stop very fast so when you click too fast yo get the error

Comment: Even if this did work you will run out of GDI resources in a couple of clicks, i think you should probably read the documentation on the classes you are using, learn how to dispose bitmaps, and learn how to appropriately handle exceptions as well, there is just a lot of wiggle room here, and its hard to answer